# How to modify a router's antenna?

Tags: antenna, wifi, power-engineering

I have tried to extend the antenna of my router in order to increase its range. I added a wire few cm long. There was no modification however in the range. The power (-db/m) was the same. Why is that?

Comment: Some routers have a repeater mode, that can extend coverage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the antenna with one that has higher gain , there are several types but in order to get high gain the antennas will have a pretty narrow beam pattern (will be directional).

A simple way to get some additional gain without changing your antenna is to use a reflector, for example http://www.binarywolf.com/249/diy-parabolic-reflector.htm

The reflector I talk about looks like
[image: reflector]